# How to delete in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

I select one id from DB and then I want to delete row with this id:

```
var ado = new mydbEntities();
var selItem = listView3.SelectedItems[0];

if (selItem != null)
{
    var selId = (from t in ado.task
                 where t.t_name == selItem.Text
                 select new { t.id});

    ado.task.DeleteOnSubmit(selId);   //this command return error
}
```

I trying delete with `DeleteOnSubmit`, but I get error.
How can I delete row from DB ?

Comment: Have you tried `var selId = (bla).ToArray()`? Though, without knowing *which* error you get, I can only guess what your problem is.

Comment: give me this error:
`System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<dbs_projekt.task>' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteOnSubmit' and no extension method`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Since you seem to be working with an `ObjectSet`, you'll need to use [DeleteObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487254.aspx);

```
var sel = (from t in ado.task
           where t.t_name == selItem.Text
           select t).FirstOrDefault();

if(sel != null)
    ado.task.DeleteObject(sel);
```

---

[DeleteOnSubmit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763473.aspx) takes an entity as a parameter, not an anonymous type. This should work better;

```
var sel = (from t in ado.task
           where t.t_name == selItem.Text
           select t).FirstOrDefault();

if(sel != null)
    ado.task.DeleteOnSubmit(sel);
```

If you want to delete multiple entities, use [DeleteAllOnSubmit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763523.aspx) which takes an enumerable of entities;

```
var sel = from t in ado.task
          where t.t_name == selItem.Text
          select t;

ado.task.DeleteAllOnSubmit(sel);
```

Comment: I still get this error: `'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<dbs_projekt.task>' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteOnSubmit' and no extension method`

Comment: yes, I tried DeleteObject(), this run with no error, but nothig's happened. Row is still in db.

Comment: @user1726810 You called `SaveChanges()` in the object context to persist the change?

Comment: yes offcourse, Iforgot. Thank you a lot
now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
var ado = new mydbEntities();
var selItem = listView3.SelectedItems[0];

if (selItem != null)
{
    var tasksToDelete =  from t in ado.task
                         where t.t_name == selItem.Text
                         select t;

    ado.task.DeleteOnSubmit(tasksToDelete);
}
```